# Ограничение в количестве потоков

Tags: qt, многопоточность, qt5

QT5. Есть цикл от 0 до 1 000 000. На каждой итерации нужно запускать одну и ту же "тяжелую" функцию, у которой аргумент - номер итерации. Работу функции хочу вывести в отдельный поток, но так же задать какое-нибудь их максимальное количество и таймаут на запуск. Скажем есть у нас 10 потоков. Работают 2. Запускаем 3-ий после таймаута в 1 секунду. И т.д. до десятого. После запуска последнего свободного - таймаут, а после ожидание завершения любого из 10 потоков - для запуска нового. Как реализовать?

Comment: QThreadPool какой-нибудь подойдет, думаю. Правда, ничего не могу сказать про паузы перед запуском потоков.

Comment: Можно какой-нибудь пример?

Comment: Когда вам нужен пример по использованию NNN просто вбейте в гугле "NNN example" и посмотрите что будет в результатах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно примерно так, используя связку `QtConcurrent` и `QThreadPool`:

```
#include <QtCore/QThreadPool>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>

#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        int maxThreads() {return _max_threads;}
        void setMaxThreads(int num) {_max_threads = num;}

        void start();

    private:
        int _max_threads;

        void longRunMethod(int i) {/*...*/}

};

void MyClass::start() {
    QThreadPool *pool = new QThreadPool(this);
    pool->setMaxThreadCount(1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        QtConcurrent::run(pool, this, &MyClass::longRunMethod, i);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(1000);
    timer->start();

    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this,pool,timer]() {
        int threads_count = pool->maxThreadCount();
        if(_max_threads > threads_count)
            return pool->setMaxThreadCount(++threads_count);

        timer->stop();
        timer->deleteLater();

        pool->waitForDone();
        pool->deleteLater();
    });
}
```

Строка `QtConcurrent::run(pool, this, &MyClass::longRunMethod, i)` не приводит к выполнению вызовов метода `MyClass::longRunMethod()` сразу, но лишь ставит каждый из них в очередь. Сначала поток будет только один, а через секунду - два, затем снова пауза и будет уже три, и т.д.

Comment: При компиляции ошибка `C:\Users\Oleg.Skrobuk\Documents\Qt\Graph\untitled8\myclass.h:45: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'MyClass::connect(QTimer*&, void (QTimer::*)(QTimer::QPrivateSignal), MyClass::start()::<lambda()>)' });` как с ней бороться?

Comment: В файле проекта добавлена строка `CONFIG += c++11` ?